# How to authenticate id password in Gdata video upload to you tube

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

To upload vedio on you tube i am using Gdata sample code.

Its working fine as it is. But in my application I need to authenticate username and password of user before user try to upload video.

Can I do it with Gdata service ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is method for client login in Youtube:

```
- (BOOL)login:(NSString *)strusername password:(NSString *)strpassword
{
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"]];

   NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Email=%@&Passwd=%@&service=youtube&source=&continue=http://www.google.com/",username,password];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [params release];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

   NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
   NSError *error;
   [request setTimeoutInterval:120];
   NSData *replyData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];    

   NSString *replyString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:replyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
   if([replyString rangeOfString:@"Auth="].location!=NSNotFound)
   {
    NSString *authToken=[[replyString componentsSeparatedByString:@"Auth="] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Auth : %@",authToken);
    return YES;
   }
   else
   {
    return NO;
   }
 }
```